# How Can I Add Multiple Pins to Google Maps API v3, and Update Them on a Click?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pull latitude and longitude coordinates from the page (which are dynamically generated from php) and place them on a google map. I'm not sure the best way to do this, but it seems like placing them in an array and redrawing on a click is the best way (yes?)

see the site here: http://yournextwebsite.se/riokultur/projekt

Here's the general premise of how it works: users select checkboxes, and then the projects (listed below the map) filter based on the categories they're in. The map also has to show all locations when the page is loaded (based on lat and long coordinates) and show/hide them as the user clicks the filters. An "active" class is added to each project that fits the users parameters. I need to return those active projects, and show them on the map.

here's the code I have so far (it draws the map, but doesn't have all the markers, or redraw on a click... Most of the code is pulled from the Google Maps site itself)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.68066002977235, 11.9091796875);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">Content</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
  }

function redraw(lat, long) {
    //add a new location for each lat/long pair
    var newLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: ''
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
  }

  initialize();

//start latitudes array
var latitudes = [];
//start longitudes array
var longitudes = [];


$('form div input').click(function(){
    //loop through active elements when a checkbox is selected/deselected
    $('p.active.filter-result').each(function(){

        //finds the active elements latitude
        var latitude = $(this).children('.latitude').text();

        //finds the active elements longitude
        var longitude = $(this).children('.longitude').text();

        //if the latitude is set, add it to the array
        if (latitude) latitudes.push(latitude);

        //if the longitude is set add it to the array
        if (longitude) longitudes.push(longitude);

    });

    //redraw the map...
    for(i=0; i<latitudes.length; i++) {
        redraw(latitude, longitude);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Why do you redraw map each time checkbox is selected? Is it expected behavior or is it what you are trying to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var initialize = function() {

    //an array of arrays, with location info
var locations = [];

    //only do this for the active results
$('p.active.filter-result').each(function(n){
    var title = $(this).children('a').text();
    var link = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    var latitude = $(this).children('.latitude').text();
    var longitude = $(this).children('.longitude').text();

        //must have a latitude and longitude to be added to the array
    if(latitude && longitude) {

            //build the title link for the tool tip
            var titleLink = '<h3><a href="' + link + '"/>' + title + '</a></h3>';

            //save the new location info
            var newLocation = [titleLink, latitude, longitude, n];

            //push it to the locations array
            locations.push(newLocation);
     }
});

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.7068353, 11.9691625),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
}

initialize();

    //recheck for active classes on each form click
$('form div input').click(function(){
    initialize();
});

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var existingMarkers = []; // to save existing markers on screen
    var popupWindow = [];
    //start latitudes array
    var latitudes = [];
    //start longitudes array
    var longitudes = [];

    function initialize() {
        var lat = 57.68066002977235;
        var lon = 11.9091796875;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        var contentString = '<div id="content">Content</div>';
        var markerTitle = 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)';

        redraw(lat, lon, contentString, markerTitle);

      }

    function redraw(lat, long, popupContent, mTitle) {
        //add a new location for each lat/long pair
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);,
            map: document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            title: mTitle
        });
        AttachPopupToMarker(marker, popupContent);
        existingMarkers.push(marker);
    }

    function AttachPopupToMarker(marker, popupContent){
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: popupContent
            });
            ClearMap(popupWindow);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            popupWindow.push(infowindow);
        });
    }

    function ClearMap(mapObjects){
        while(mapObjects[0]){
            mapObjects.pop().setMap(null);
        }
    }

    initialize();    

    $('form div input').click(function(){
        //loop through active elements when a checkbox is selected/deselected
        $('p.active.filter-result').each(function(){

            //clear latitudes array
            latitudes = [];
            //clear longitudes array
            longitudes = [];
            //finds the active elements latitude
            var latitude = $(this).children('.latitude').text();

            //finds the active elements longitude
            var longitude = $(this).children('.longitude').text();

            //if the latitude is set, add it to the array
            if (latitude) latitudes.push(latitude);

            //if the longitude is set add it to the array
            if (longitude) longitudes.push(longitude);

        });

        //clear previous marker
        ClearMap(existingMarkers);

        //redraw the map...
        for(i=0; i<latitudes.length; i++) {
            redraw(latitude, longitude, '', '');
        }
    });
});
```